Query to fetch multiple customer numbers for a single user in user table
In our airline industry, we have a requirement to find out more than one customer number for a single login in AIR_USER table. The table structure is below.



ROW_ID
LOGIN
CUST_NUM
FULL_NAME




1-3EW
SUNILK
3001
SUNIL KUMAR


1-3QL
SUNILK
3002
SUNIL KUMAR


1-4FV
DILIPK
1001
DILEEP KUMAR


1-5TF
DILIPK
1003
DILEEP KUMAR


1-4BX
RAVIP
2002
RAVI PRADEEP



I used the below query, but it is taking huge time as cost and cardinality is into lakhs. Also, this table has almost million records as it contains all the user information.
SELECT 
  DISTINCT LOGIN, CUST_NUM, COUNT(CUST_NUM) 
FROM AIR_USER 
GROUP BY 
  LOGIN, CUST_NUM 
HAVING COUNT(CUST_NUM) > 1 
ORDER BY LOGIN;

Could you assist if this query is correct ? If correct, could you assist in refining the query.
Query to fetch multiple customer numbers for a single user in user table

The query looks allright, You are doing the Count two times thoug but i dont't know if that could be done better. You Should have Indexes on Login and CUT_NUM and a combined index on LOGIN_CUST_NUM. So what does your table structure look like are there indexes? Indexes boost performance tremendiously. Without the table structure it would be hard to tell you why performance suffers. As well the load your server is on. Is there heavy load on the server. On which machine does it run? Do you use SSD as Hard drive? One would need an oracle config perhaps.

Please don't use local words here. People from elsewhere have no idea what is into lakhs means.

Don't use DISTINCT and GROUP BY in the same (sub-) query. GROUP BY will return a single row per group so DISTINCT is pointless.
You also do not want to include CUST_NUM in the GROUP BY:
SELECT LOGIN,
       LISTAGG(CUST_NUM, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cust_num) AS cust_nums,
       COUNT(CUST_NUM) 
FROM   AIR_USER 
GROUP BY LOGIN
HAVING COUNT(CUST_NUM) > 1 
ORDER BY LOGIN

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE air_user (ROW_ID, LOGIN, CUST_NUM, FULL_NAME) AS
SELECT '1-3EW', 'AMAJAK', 3001, 'AMAJA KUMAR'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1-3QL', 'AMAJAK', 3002, 'AMAJA KUMAR'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1-4FV', 'BEEJAK', 1001, 'BEEJA KUMAR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1-5TF', 'BEEJAK', 1003, 'BEEJA KUMAR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1-4BX', 'CHARAP',  2002, 'CHARA PRADEEP' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



LOGIN
CUST_NUMS
COUNT(CUST_NUM)




AMAJAK
3001,3002
2


BEEJAK
1001,1003
2



or, if you don't want to list the cust_num and only want to know the login you can simplify the query to:
SELECT LOGIN
FROM   AIR_USER 
GROUP BY LOGIN
HAVING COUNT(CUST_NUM) > 1 
ORDER BY LOGIN

Outputs:



LOGIN




AMAJAK


BEEJAK



fiddle

If you are looking for LOGIN that has more than one different CUST_NUM than you should use
HAVING COUNT(Distinct CUST_NUM) > 1
like bellow:
SELECT LOGIN
FROM   AIR_USER 
GROUP BY LOGIN
HAVING COUNT(Distinct CUST_NUM) > 1 

... without Distinct keyword it will count multiple appearances of the same CUST_NUM as another one.
If it is a large dataset you are running your query against - maybe you could test the performance of the MODEL clause. Not sure, but in my experiance it was quite often faster than other options. Try it and see if it is faster or not.
Select LOGIN
From  ( SELECT  LOGIN, CNT
        FROM  ( SELECT ROWNUM "RN", LOGIN, CUST_NUM, 0 "CNT"
                FROM   AIR_USER
              )
              MODEL Partition By (LOGIN)
                    Dimension By (RN)
                    MEASURES (CUST_NUM, CNT)
              RULES ( CNT[ANY] = Count(DISTINCT CUST_NUM)[RN <= CV()] )
        )
Where CNT = 2

